# Have any Australians played Carlsen OTB, other than Smerdon and Smirnov?

Tags: history, master-games, carlsen, otb-chess

There was [Smerdon vs. Carlsen (2016)](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1831469) 1/2-1/2, and now there is [Smirnov vs. Carlsen (2022)](https://www.chess.com/events/2022-fide-chess-olympiad/06/Smirnov_Anton-Carlsen_Magnus) 0-1.  I'm not aware of any other games between Australian players and Carlsen.

**Question**: Have any Australians played Carlsen OTB, other than Smerdon and Smirnov?

ABC News suggests there have been other games:

> Queensland Grandmaster David Smerdon is **one of the few Australians to have faced Carlsen over the board**, holding him to a draw at the 2016 Chess Olympiad in Azerbaijan.
> <sub>[ABC News](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-11-26/kings-gambit-magnus-carlsen-cement-legacy-greatest-chess-player/100646162), 2021.</sub>

I'm guessing people might be downvoting because it's basically impossible to eliminate the possibility that there were Carlsen vs. Australian-player undocumented games played e.g. in a bar.  I'm mostly just interested in what's available in databases.  I personally don't own a database, and I'm not sure of an efficient method to check online databases for "Australian player".  The answer might very well  be "there are no others recorded" ([cmgchess's comment](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/have-any-australians-played-carlsen-otb-other-than-smerdon-and-smirnov#comment65360_40314) seems to suggest this), but I don't know.

Comment: fide profile only shows smerdon. im not sure if fide profile publicly shows records only after 2003. so only smerdon and smirnov in fide rated games?

Comment: https://ratings.fide.com/a_data_opponents.php?pl=1503014

Comment: I cannot fathom why a perfectly good on-topic question like this one is downvoted so much.

Comment: "one of the few" seems like some good weasel-wording for "we couldn't find any others but didn't really want to commit to saying 'only'"

Answer (score 3):

[Zhao Zong-Yuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhao_Zong-Yuan) played Carlsen in the first round of the [2007 World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_World_Cup_2007), losing [both](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1479855) [games](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1480099).